# How to show that $f: (0, \infty)\longrightarrow\Bbb R$ defined by $f(x)= 1/x$ is not Lipschitz continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, lipschitz-functions

> How to show that $f: (0, \infty)\longrightarrow\Bbb R$ defined by $f(x)= 1/x$ is not Lipschitz continuous?

If $K$ is a Lipschitz constant, I got 
$$K\ge \frac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{|x-y|}=\frac1{|xy|}$$
 and then I don't know what to do. I thought maybe $xy\to 0$ then there is no $K$ because $|1/xy|\to\infty$. Is it right?

Comment: What? I don't understand what you're trying to do in that attempt you posted. Can you explain your reasoning a bit more?

Answer (score 2):

By definition,
$$ f\text{ Lipschitz}\implies |f(x)-f(y)|\le K|x-y|.$$
But take $x=1/n$, $y=1/2n$, $n\in\Bbb N$.
$$|f(x)-f(y)|=|1/(1/n) - 1/(1/2n)|=n$$
And now...